# java annotations: library to override annotations with xml files

Tags: java, xml, annotations, metaprogramming, metadata

Java has annotations and that is good. However, some developers feel that it is best to annotate code with metadata using xml files - others prefer annotations but would use metadata to override annotations in source code.

I am writing a Java framework that uses annotations. The question is: is there a standard way to define and parse metadata from xml files. I think this is something every framework that uses annotations could benefit from but I can seem to find something like this on the Internet.

Must I roll my own xml parsing/validation or has someone already done something like this?

Comment: +1 excellent question. I'm eager to find answers.

Comment: there is no standard, you can check out hibernate or ejb3 sources to see how they do it, but i think it would be faster to roll out your own framework(it could become standard in the future).

Comment: http://beust.com/weblog/archives/000157.html <- this might help

Comment: Hibernate is an example of a framework where you can use either Java5 annotations or XML metadata. Both get parsed into a neutral meta-data model. But there's a lot of history there, so it may not be the best way to go about things.

Comment: @01 Your pointing to the blog of Cedric Beust seem good enough for me, to be qualified as an answer :-)

Comment: What's the use case for this framework? I might be wrong but it feels like that if you want to override some annotation then it was wrong to use the annotation in the first place. For me annotation==source code. If you want something configurable later it should be in the XML in the first place

Comment: @Gregory: annotations are just a way of defining meta data for your classes. XML is a perfectly valid way of achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a standard way, but here are some Java frameworks who does it:

- [JPA](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr220/index.html) - check ejb-3_0-fr-spec-persistence.pdf
- [Spring Framework](http://www.springframework.org/)
- [TestNG](http://beust.com/weblog/archives/000157.html) - as written above, though I think it focuses to much on the annotation side rather than the actual configuration he tries to achieve
- [Seam Framework](http://www.seamframework.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the [Annox](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/User+guide) library which does exactly what you need. With Annox you can read arbitrary annotations from XML.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you want, but [the backport175 project](http://backport175.codehaus.org/) has an implementation of annotations for Java versions before Java 5.

It has some of the functionality you search in that it will read both its own style implementations and "real" annotations if they are present. Maybe this can be used as a starting point to build a more general framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use JAXB  http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/
You would write the xsd for your metadata file, generate JAXB classes that can help you parse the xml files.